# What is the C++ equivalent of Objective C "@property (nonatomic, retain)"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, properties

I am am wondering how to create properly properties in C++. In Objective C, I use "@property" (in general with the (nonatomic, retain) attributes).

What is the proper way in C++ ?

Thanks !!

Comment: There's no first-class notion of properties in C++. Some vendor-specific extensions to that effect exist, but not (IIRC) in the Mac world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Seva said, there are no properties in that kind of sense in C++. What you could do: write a class with a [boost::share_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) member variable, and optionally write getter and setter for that member. But that isn't even really necessary, although maybe deemed good behaviour.

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<std::string> StringPtrT;

class A {
public:
    void setStringProperty(StringPtrT s) { this->string_property = s; }
    StringPtrT getStringProperty() const { return this->string_property; }

protected:
    StringPtrT string_property;
}
```

The shared pointer will deal with the sharing and reference counting, basically simulating some kind of "retain" behaviour. IIRC boost shared_ptr types are always atomic, when it comes to updateing the reference counts. However, access to the object itself (de-referencing the pointer) will be non-atomic. You will have to deal with that yourself, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

@Ame's code is correct, but there's no particular requirement to use `shared_ptr` here. I am very torn on the use of `shared_ptr` broadly. It can be useful, but introduces a lot of subtle complexity in my experience. It is not the traditional C++ approach. C++ often prefers strong object ownership rather than shared ownership (which is the common model in ObjC). If you do use `shared_ptr`, it's built-in for Cocoa platforms, so you don't need boost. You may want to read [Wrapping C++ – Take 2, Part 2](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-2-493) to get a sense of some of the complexities around `shared_ptr` (it's a little dated, and some of it is not applicable to ARC code).

That said, @Ame's approach is essentially correct. But you typically would use copying for simple properties rather than `shared_ptr`. (This is particularly true for strings, which you also copy in most ObjC code.) For someone looking for a style guide, I typically recommend [Google's](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml). It's not perfect, but it's very well considered, and it's good to start with something that at least is known to work for a lot of people before inventing your own. *(EDIT: See @Matthieu M.'s comment below for a dissenting opinion.)*

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  ...
  int num_entries() const { return num_entries_; }
  void set_num_entries(int num_entries) { num_entries_ = num_entries; }

 private:
  int num_entries_;
};
```

Note the `private:` is correct here. I disagree with @Ame's use of `protected:`. Just like ObjC, you should use accessors even inside of classes, and definitely you should use them in subclasses. Allowing subclasses to directly access ivars is fragile. It requires subclasses to have special knowledge of their superclass.

For string properties and other simple or immutable objects, you should generally use the copy constructor rather than anything like `shared_ptr`. For more complex, mutable objects, C++ typically encourages strong object ownership rather than shared ownership. So there should (in general) be some one object responsible for creating, managing, and destroying that other complex object. Everyone else should just get references from the object's owner. They should never create or destroy the object themselves.

It's not that shared or strict ownership is better IMO. It's just that shared ownership is the ObjC way and all code works that way (and it is extremely elegant in that). Strict ownership is more the C++ way (as much as C++ can be said to have "a way") and trying to shoehorn shared ownership into it is often fragile.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the assertion that Google's style guide is very well considered and a good start. Google's style guide is directed at people having a mixed C and C++ codebase (thus exceptions being banned, for example). For pure C++ code bases, it is definitely not something that should be used. Beginners should be encouraged to use other resources (see the C++ tag for excellent books, read the GotW site, ...) before an exposure to Google's style guide so that they can take its advices with a grain of salt.

Comment: I will defer to @MatthieuM. here on pure C++ projects. I am primarily an ObjC developer who bridges often to mixed C and C++ code. As he notes, Google's style is designed for that kind of case, and so has worked reasonably well (if not perfectly) for me.